# jQuery inconsistent behavior across browsers when cloning a textarea

Tags: jquery, clone

```js
$(function() {
  var $t = $("<textarea>", {
    text: "foobar"
  });
  $t.val("");
  console.log($t.val());
  console.log($t.html());

  var $copy = $t.clone();
  console.log($copy.val());
  console.log($copy.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The code above logs "", "foobar", "foobar", "foobar" on Firefox 42.0 and Chrome 43, logs "", "foobar", "", "foobar" on IE 11 and Chrome 47.

According to documentation of clone() method, user data typed into textarea is not copied.

It seems that the behavior on Chrome 47 is not correct, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

> To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed. Tags that can contain other elements should be paired with a closing tag.

So, I'll change `$("<textarea>")` to `$("<textarea></textarea>")`.

Comment: I changed $("<textarea>") to $("<textarea></textarea>"), but it made no difference.